# Change UITable Section Title color

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to change the color of UITableView section header.

Comment: @Suriya, Just few minutes ago I came to know how to accept the answers. Now I will Always accept the answers. Thanks for informing me abt it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code for your answer

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 UIView *tempView=[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,44)]autorelease];
 tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
 UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,44)];
 tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 tempLabel.text=@"MY HEADER";
 [tempView addSubview: tempLabel];
 [tempLabel release];
 return tempView;
}
```

This will give you a redColor header. Change the color as per your requirement...

**Edited (as per Harsh):**

Since the view in header will overlap your First cell so increase the height of the header

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
return 50; 
}
```

hAPPY cODING........

Comment: both tempView and tempLabel should really be autoreleased in this code.

Comment: thanks zem for pointing out.. As i have wriiten the code directly over here so have forgot. Also Please set the frames as per your convinience...

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 50;
}

Comment: Thanks Suriya but I found that one should also use ablove function to set the height of the section header otheraise the header name will be overlapped with the table cell.

Comment: Yes the height must be greater than the views size..I have edited and added that too in the answer `Getting a vote is the best thanks...`

Answer (score 1):

Use `- (UIView  *)tableView:(UITableView  *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
This method is part of UITableViewDelegate
Return the view with label. you can now configure label color.