# Change color title UITable static section

Tags: xamarin.ios, tableview

I have two UITable static sections in my application with both different headers.
The color of the header must be changed because the custom background.

How can I do this solution like ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715390/change-uitable-section-title-color) ) in my MonoTouch application?

Because I use static sections, I don't have a UITableViewSource where I can do stuff in.

#### My solution (thanks to Krumelur)

```
[Export("tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:")]
UIView GetViewForHeaderInSecion (UITableView tableview, int section)
{
    UIView view = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 300, 0));
    view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

    UILabel label = new UILabel (new RectangleF (15, 5, 300, 25));
    label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    label.TextColor = UIColor.White;
    label.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black;
    label.ShadowOffset = new SizeF(0, 1);
    label.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(18);

    if (section == 0) {
        label.Text = "First section";
    } else {
        label.Text = "Second section";
    }

    view.AddSubview(label);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to export the missing method in your controller. Something like:

```
[Export("tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:")]
UIView GetViewForHeaderInSection(UITableView tableview, int section
{
// return your UIView with whatever background color here
}
```

Note that you cannot change the color of the predefined view but have to return an entire view instead.